# querySelectorAll is not finding dynamically added elements with custom attribute

Tags: javascript

I am creating two way binding between JS Object and UI in below fiddle, code is big to post Please check http://jsfiddle.net/bpH6Z/20/

I am using the code like below

```
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[" + data_attr + "]  *[bd='" + prop_name +  "']");
```

I have mentioned the problem line in big comments, can be identified easily. My problem is I am adding elements to binded dynamicaly using JS, when I change the value in UI, the same value is not reflected in other places. The problem is querySelectorAll is faling to find elements with same attribute. It is finding only first occurrence. Please look into the issue.

Comment: I 'm sorry but you are asking for someone to debug the code for you, which is IMHO unacceptable. If you have made a good faith effort to debug and determined that `querySelectorAll` is indeed the problem (which I consider *highly* unlikely), then make a fiddle with just 5-6 lines of code that shows `querySelectorAll` failing and describe the problem here.

Comment: @jon Please see this fiddle same problem here http://jsfiddle.net/8drC4/

Comment: That was much better, and it allowed me to see that if you fix a couple of small errors it [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/8drC4/2/).

Comment: @jon why the same is code failing in my first fiddle?

Comment: Put the two versions side by side and compare.

Comment: @jon No change in the code I am using and code you have provided..

Comment: Your divs are wrong in your example @Exception You seem to have got your div1 and div vars mixed up http://jsfiddle.net/8drC4/4/ so they didn't match your selector

Comment: @TommyBs Yes thanks for the answer, but I could not find the problem in my first fiddle why that is not working. Could you please look into that. I have clearly mentioned where the selector is not working. But could not find the issue from last two hours..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give me negative votes and let myself realize to not to waste my time with silly mistakes. In my first fiddle I have written "bata-bind" instead of "data-bind". That was the mistake.